# Issue authenticating user with Vue 3 app using Express proxy server (CORS)

Tags: express, cors, vuejs3

I am trying to play around with Vue 3 and express using [this API](https://gist.github.com/leptos-null/d663802b663def167bf4c4c736d7e41f)
I can successfully reach it using Postman and curl. However my Vue app it's not working. I figured out the proxy server is talking to my app, when I make a login submission on my vue app running here http://localhost:8080/login I can see that the token is fetched and is being applied to the authorization header. But for some reason getting user details isn't' working I think due to CORS

any help is appreciated thanks

**//proxy-server/server.js**

```
//proxy-server/server.js


// Use Cors
app.use(cors({ origin: 'http://localhost:8080', credentials: true,  optionsSuccessStatus: 200 })); 
app.use(express.json());

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Hello, this is the proxy server!');
});

// Handle OPTIONS request for preflight checks
app.options('/authentication', cors());
app.options('/users/me', cors());
app.get('/v2.1/authentication', cors(), async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const response = await axios.get('https://blood.arc.cubeapis.com/v2.1/authentication', {
      headers: req.headers,
    });

    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:8080');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, Content-Type, Access-Control-Request-Headers, Authorization');
    res.header('Access-Control-Max-Age', '86400');

    res.json(response.data);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Proxy Error:', error.message);
    res.status(500).json({ error: 'Internal Server Error located  @ /v2.1/authentication' });
  }
});

app.post('/authentication', cors(), async (req, res) => {
  console.log('Received POST request:', req.method, req.url);
  console.log('Request headers:', req.headers);
  console.log('Request body:', req.body);

  try {
    const response = await axios.post('https://blood.arc.cubeapis.com/v2.1/authentication', req.body);

    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:8080');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, Content-Type, Access-Control-Request-Headers, Authorization');
    res.header('Access-Control-Max-Age', '86400');

    res.json(response.data);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Proxy Error:', error.message);
    res.status(500).json({ error: 'Internal Server Error /authentication' });
  }
});

app.get('/users/me', cors(), async (req, res) => {
  console.log('Received GET request:', req.method, req.url);
  console.log('Request headers:', req.headers);
  console.log('Request body:', req.body);
  console.log('Forwarding to:', 'https://blood.arc.cubeapis.com' + req.url);
  try {
    
    const response = await axios.get('https://blood.arc.cubeapis.com/v2.1/users/me', {
      headers: req.headers,
    });

    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:8080');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, Content-Type, Access-Control-Request-Headers, Authorization');
    res.header('Access-Control-Max-Age', '86400');

    res.json(response.data);


  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Proxy Error:', error.message);
    res.status(500).json({ error: 'Internal Server Error /v2.1/users/me', details: error.message });
    
  }
});
```

Comment: GET
http://localhost:3000/users/me
[HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error 262ms]

Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at ‘http://localhost:3000/users/me’. (Reason: Credential is not supported if the CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ is ‘*’).

Comment: start:proxy] }
[start:proxy] Request body: {}
[start:proxy] Forwarding to: https://blood.arc.cubeapis.com/users/me
[start:proxy] Proxy Error: Hostname/IP does not match certificate's altnames: Host: localhost. is not in the cert's altnames: DNS:*.arc.cubeapis.com